# Computer restarts every 5 seconds after beeping sounds

Tags: motherboard, bios, computer-building

Me and my brother where building a computer with these parts:

- Crucial BX200
- Corsair CX-M Series CX450M
- Crucial
- Cooler Master N200
- Gigabyte GA-H110M-S2H
- Intel Core i5-6400 / 2.7 GHz

As far as we know everything besides the hard disk is put in correctly.
note we are trying to load the bios since we are without opperating system.
However. The problem is once we start the computer. It gives back 4 big bleeping sounds and 1 short bleeping sound and restarts afterward over and over.

Does anyone know what is going on? I was searching online but I couldn't find what 4 long bleeps and 1 short means. We are thinking the motherboard is broken but we are probably wrong.

Comment: Sounds like a processor problem...http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/faq-page.aspx?fid=816

Comment: How is it one? I couldn't find the 4 long 1 short beep in the link you provided either. Sorry I am still very confused why it is doing this.

Comment: Remove everything you can.  All cards that are not necessary.  Populate the minimum RAM.  Reseat your processor.  Test.  See if you get the same result.

Comment: After we removed the ram we saw some dust so we cleaned it up a bit. We put everything back up and it worked. Oh well. Seems like it is working now. thanks for the help!